# Why doesn't my search algorithm work for Project Euler 31?

Tags: java, algorithm, search, data-structures, tree

Problem 31

> In England the currency is made up of pound, £, and pence, p, and
>   there are eight coins in general circulation: 1p, 2p, 5p, 10p, 20p,
>   50p, £1 (100p) and £2 (200p). It is possible to make £2 in the
>   following way: 1×£1 + 1×50p + 2×20p + 1×5p + 1×2p + 3×1p How many
>   different ways can £2 be made using any number of coins?

```
static int[] nums = {200,100,50,20,10,5,2,1};
static int size = nums.length;
static HashMap<Integer,Integer> pivots = new HashMap<>();

public static int checkSum(HashMap<Integer,Integer> pivots){

    int target = 200;
    int sum = 0;

    for(Integer key: pivots.keySet()){
        int pivot = pivots.get(key);
        sum +=  nums[pivot];
        if(sum > target) return 1;
    }

    if(sum < target) return -1;

    return 0;
}

public static void shift(HashMap<Integer,Integer> pivots, int pivot_node){

    if(pivots.size() + nums[pivots.get(1)] == 201 && pivots.get(1) != 0){

        int p_1_value = pivots.get(1);   //this part checks whether the  current node(which is the first node)                                                                  
                                  //has reached children of all 1. 
                             //Which means it's time to shift the root node.
        pivots.clear();
        pivots.put(1 , p_1_value);
        shift(pivots, 1);
        return;
    }

    if(pivots.get(pivot_node) != size - 1) {
        pivots.put(pivot_node, pivots.get(pivot_node) + 1);
    }
    else{
        shift(pivots , pivot_node - 1);
    }

}



public static void branch(HashMap<Integer,Integer> pivots){
    pivots.put(pivots.size() + 1, pivots.get(pivots.size()));
}

public static int search(){
    int bool = checkSum(pivots);

    int n = 0;
    int count = 0;

    while(n < 25) {
        count++;
        if (bool == 0) {
            n++;     // if the sum is equal to 200, we shift the last 
                     //pivot to the next lower number.               
            shift(pivots, pivots.size());

        }else if (bool == -1) {   
            branch(pivots); //if the sum is less than 200, we make a new pivot with value of the last pivot.
        }else if (bool == 1) {    
            shift(pivots, pivots.size());  //if the sum is greater than 200,
                                          //we shift to the last pivot to the next lower number. 
        }
        bool = checkSum(pivots);
    }
    return n;
}

public static void main(String[] args){

    pivots.put(1,0);

    int n = search();

    System.out.print("\n\n------------\n\n"+ "n: " + n);

}
```

This is an algorithm that searches for combinations of a set that add up to a target. It's kind of like a depth first tree search without using a tree. Each pivot represents node on the "tree". The shift() method changes the value of the node to the next lower value. The branch() method creates a new node with the same value of the last node. The checkSum() method checks whether the sum of the pivots are <,= or > the target, 200.

The correct answer for the number of ways is supposed to be around 73000. But my algorithm only returns about 300 ways.
I have no idea why this happens because my algorithm should reach every single possible combination that equals 200.

This is a visualization of how my algorithm works:

[image: img]

Comment: you should add also the problem statement and link to it (not everyone can remember all Project Euler problems)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your search algorithm doesn't find all possible combinations of coins that make up £2 because you are only shifting the "last pivot" to the next lower number, when you should be considering the items before that last one too.

Your algorithm will find this combination:

**100, 50, 20, 20, 5, 2, 2, 1**

but not this:

**100, 20, 20, 20, 10, 5, 2, 2, 1**

The second combination does not have the value 50 in it, but your algorithm breaks down the coin values backwards to forwards only -i.e. it will never break down 50 until all the following "pivots" are 1. You can easily see that if you print your `HashMap<Integer,Integer> pivots` every time the counter n is incremented.

You could try to fix your code by amending it to `shift()` using not only the last pivot but all the distinct previous pivots too. However, doing so you will create a lot of duplicates, so you'll need to keep a list of the distinct found combinations.

Another way to solve problem 31 is by using Dynamic Programming. Dynamic programming is best when it comes to problems that can be broken down in smaller bits. For example the solution of the same problem but where
`target = 2` can be used to solve the problem where `target = 5`, which can be used to solve the problem where `target = 10` and so on.

Good luck!